# How to share data from application in kotlin android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, button, share

I have a button on which when I click, it shows an option on where to share all the data in that activity such as title, link, image video etc. In Android Studio in Kotlin or Java.

I tried the code given below using intent:

```
  btShare.setOnClickListener {
        val shareText = tvTit.text.toString()

        // Create the Intent
        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText)
        }

        // Start the chooser dialog
        val chooserIntent = 
            Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with")
        startActivity(chooserIntent)
    }
```

but it shows message "no app can perform this action".
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `type` to your intent as recommended by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleSend):

```kotlin
// Create the text message with a string.
val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMessage)
    type = "text/plain"
}

// Try to invoke the intent.
try {
    startActivity(sendIntent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    // Define what your app should do if no activity can handle the intent.
}
```

Comment: yes, i added different types for sharing different type of data such as: for images i used type = "image/*" and for text i used  type = "text/plain" but my work is done without using try catch and i used choose intent :  
val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share with")
startActivity(chooserIntent)